# TinyIOC and multiple user specified factories for type

Tags: c#, reactiveui, tinyioc

I'm currently trying to wire up a custom [ReactiveUI IMutableDependencyResolver](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/rxui5-master/ReactiveUI/IDependencyResolver.cs) using TinyIOC. And I'm struggling with the fact that ReactiveUI wants to register multiple interface implementations with user specified factories. Which TinyIOC does not seem to support.

My implementation seems to overwrite the previous registration everytime register is called again. Any suggestions?

```
#region IMutableDependencyResolver implementation

public void Register(Func<object> factory, Type serviceType, string contract = null)
{
  TinyIOC.TinyIOCContainer.Current.Register(serviceType, (a, b)=>
  { 
    var result = factory();
    return result;
  }, contract);
}

#endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically for resolvers like this, you have to do the multiple registration bit yourself - i.e. instead of registering the type directly, you have to register "The list of services registered". It's kind of a pain.

If you don't need service injection via constructors, I'd encourage you to just use the built-in one, it's actually Pretty Good™.

**Update:** Finally found some of the code I wrote to work around a similar problem in AutoFac:
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    var container = default(IContainer);

```
#region Don't actually read this terrible code

// NB: This garbage exists in order to work around the fact that
// Autofac doesn't support multiple registrations for the same type
// (i.e. GetAllServices), but RxUI relies on it.
var registrations = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string>, List<Type>>();
RxApp.ConfigureServiceLocator(
    (t, s) => s != null ? container.ResolveNamed(s, t) : container.Resolve(t),
    (t, s) => {
        var type = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(t);
        var ret = (IEnumerable<Type>)container.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<Type>>(type.FullName);
        return ret.Select(x => Activator.CreateInstance(x)).ToArray();
    },
    (c, t, s) => {
        // NB: This is the hackiest hack of hack to work around a bug in RxUI
        if (container != null) return;

        var pair = Tuple.Create(t, s);
        if (!registrations.ContainsKey(pair)) registrations[pair] = new List<Type>();

        registrations[pair].Add(c);
    });

foreach (var kvp in registrations) {
    if (kvp.Value.Count == 1) {
        var reg = builder.RegisterType(kvp.Value[0]).As(kvp.Key.Item1);
        if (kvp.Key.Item2 != null) reg.Named(kvp.Key.Item2, kvp.Key.Item1);
    } else {
        var type = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(kvp.Key.Item1);
        builder.RegisterInstance(kvp.Value).As<IEnumerable<Type>>().Named<IEnumerable<Type>>(type.FullName);
    }
}

#endregion
```

Comment: Hey Paul, that's the problem. The app I'm currently porting makes heavy use of constructor injection :-)